# Acessar um elemento dentro da mesma hierarquia de elementos

Tags: html, jquery

Seguinte, tenho essa situação:

```
<html>
  <g class="children">
     <g>
        <rect class="child" data-id="xpto"></rect>
     </g>
     <rect class="xpto"></rect>
     <text class="texto">
        <tspan></tspan>
     </text>
   </g>
</html>
```

Preciso sair do elemento "text" e acessar o atributo "data-id" do "rect" que está dentro do elemento "g". Alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: $('.texto').prev('.xpto');

Comment: O alvo desse comando é o rect da classe .xpto ? estou querendo acessar o rect da class .child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que a forma mais simples de se fazer isso é usar o `prev` duas vezes para chegar ao elemento desejado.

Em seguida, basta usar o `children` para acessar o `rect` e ler o atributo `data-id`.

```js
const $el = $('.texto')

// Acessar o `<g>`, voltando dois elementos:
const $g = $el.prev().prev()

// Acessar o `<rect>` dentro do `<g>`:
const $rect = $g.children('rect')

// Capturar os atributos desejados:
const dataId = $rect.attr('data-id')

console.log(dataId)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
  <g class="children">
     <g>
        <rect class="child" data-id="xpto"></rect>
     </g>
     <rect class="xpto"></rect>
     <text class="texto">
        <tspan></tspan>
     </text>
   </g>
</html>
```

Fazendo usando só uma linha de código:

```
const id = $('.texto').prev().prev().children('rect').attr('data-id')
console.log(id)
```

---

No entanto, o jQuery nos dá diversas formas de alcançar o mesmo resultado. A solução acima contempla uma das várias formas de se fazer. Uma outra delas seria usando o `prevUntil`, `parent`, etc.

#### Referência:

- [`.prev()` (jQuery)](https://api.jquery.com/prev/);
- [`.children()` (jQuery)](https://api.jquery.com/children);
- [`.attr()` (jQuery)](https://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [.parent](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) para buscar o pai do elemento `text` (nesse caso retornaria o primeiro `g` da árvore, o que contém a `class="children"` e a partir dele procurar pelo `rect` referente ao pai, após encontrar o elemento na árvore você pode usar o [data](https://api.jquery.com/data/) para pegar o `data-id` do elemento. Segue um código de exemplo

```js
var el = $( ".texto" ).parent();
var id = el.find('g rect.child').data('id');
console.log(id);

//Ou pra simplificar
var data_id = $(".texto").parent().find('g rect.child').data('id');
console.log(data_id);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <g class="children">
     <g>
        <rect class="child" data-id="xpto"></rect>
     </g>
     <rect class="xpto"></rect>
     <text class="texto">
        <tspan></tspan>
     </text>
   </g>
</html>
```